# Nexus url of ivy (ant) publish task

Tags: jenkins, ivy, nexus

When using the Ivy:publish (ant)task, is there some reliable way to retrieve the URL of the published artifact.

The reason we like to know this is because we build the artifact on jenkins and would like to link the 2 processes together so we know which build produced a specific artifact. since we trigger builds fairly often and in parralel just getting the url of the last published artifact is unreliable.

Comment: What's the matter, you cannot concatenate the URL of the repository with a path to your artifact? I suppose you have the version number as well? I'm not sure your question is clear enough. Perhaps you should add some examples of what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: At this time we are publishing as snapshots so the URL is not known

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the exact URL of the snapshot by using the REST API:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/23674267-How-can-I-retrieve-a-snapshot-if-I-don-t-know-the-exact-filename-